# Old File from storage is not being deleted on update Laravel

Tags: laravel, file, storage, unlink

I am trying to delete the existing image from the storage while the new image is being updated.
But everytime the new image is inserted retaining the previous ones.

When I dd the image from database to unlink, I get full url
i.e.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/teacger-image/1598097262-85508.jpg
```

While only `teacher-image/1598097262-85508.jpg`
has been stored in the database.

**Function to delete the image**

```
public function deleteImageFromStorage($value)
{
    if (!empty($value)) {
        File::delete('public/' . $value);
    }
}
```

I have called the method in the controller when there is image posted during update.

**update method includes**

```
 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $teacher->deleteImageFromStorage($teacher->image);
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $filename =  time() . '-' . mt_rand(0, 100000) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = $file->storeAs('teacher-image', $filename);
            $teacher->image = $path;
        }
```

Also I have used `Storage::delete()` and `unlink` as well but none of them seem to work.

help

Comment: Can you provide the code from the update method too?

Comment: I have updated the code Adrian sir

Comment: Did you save the image in public folder?

Comment: I have public/teacger-image and then the files over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this to solve my problem.
The url was being taken by the configuration set on filesystems.php under config file.

```
public function deleteImageFromStorage($value)
{
    $path_explode = explode('/', (parse_url($value))['path']); //breaking the full url 
    $path_array = [];
    array_push($path_array, $path_explode[2], $path_explode[3]); // storing the value of path_explode 2 and 3 in path_array array
    $old_image = implode('/', $path_array);

    if ($old_image) {
        Storage::delete($old_image);
    }
}
```

If someone goes through the same problem in the future, this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've been deleting files in Laravel.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ImagesController extends Controller
{
    public function deleteImageFromStorage($value)
    {
        if ( file_exists( storage_path($value) ) ) {
            Storage::delete($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage.

Comment: Is it possible to post the original store method? It seems to me that the db entry is not only saving the path but the whole link including the host name, which will pose a problem if you port the site. Have you checked the value stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your deleteImageFromStorage method to this:

```
public function deleteImageFromStorage($value)
{
    if (!empty($value)) {
        File::delete(public_path($value));
    }
}
```

Comment: You already add `use File;` at the top of the code right?

Comment: Yes 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
This one

Comment: try change that to File only, without Illuminate\Support\Facades\

Comment: never mind but not working.
I dont know why I get http://127.0.0.1:8000 also when I dd the image retrieved.
I am pretty sure this must be the issue.
Tried parsing the url but didnt have a good idea on it.

Comment: Try dd the public_path($value) did it show the right path? try to paste it in your browser to see the image